# read.FlowSet unable to Open Folder of FCS files

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to test out using R on a Win7 machine to analyze flow samples.  So far I've had success working with a single FCS file, but no luck when trying to load a folder of just FCS files into a flowSet:

```
> library(flowCore)
> library(flowStats) 
...
> library(flowViz)
> library(flowUtils)
> library(flowClust)
...

>files.test1 = list.files('E:/Set/', all.files=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
> set.test1 = read.flowSet(files.test1)
Error in file(filename, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'E:/Set/.': Permission denied
```

While I wouldn't call myself great with R, I feel like I have a pretty good working knowledge of running it from a Linux prospective.  I tried changing the path to `'E:/Set'` and `'E:\\Set'` just to make sure I'm not missing anything there.

I'm also [running as administrator](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Winbugs-under-R-s-error-message-td897312.html),  and pointing [directly](http://grokbase.com/t/r/bioconductor/078cpmq00v/bioc-cannot-open-file-reason-permission-denied-in-file-file-r) to a folder with [no other file types in it](http://grokbase.com/t/r/bioconductor/1296y8wqf8/bioc-problems-reading-in-a-flowset).  I found [this solution](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Permission-denied-in-Windows-7-td3584539.html) which looks at the same error from a different starting point.  My understanding from that is that in the end they had to point directly at the file to overcome the error.  Is that the case?

If I'm not approaching this correctly, what would the correct way be to load a series (too many to reasonably type out one at a time) of FCS files into a flowSet?  Should I not be using flowSet at all?  Looking at the [workflow example](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/highthroughputassays/flowWorkFlow.pdf) that seems to be the intention of flowSet.

---

Update:

Dropping the `all.files=TRUE` seems to allow the line to run without error and collects all the files anyway:

```
> files.test1 = list.files('E:/Set', full.names=TRUE)
> set.test1 = read.flowSet(files.test1)
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

The reason I'm not writing this as an answer and accepting it is because I don't know why that's true.  After looking at the error, it appeared to me as though it were trying to read: `[Path]\.` as an actual file.  Thus dropping the `all.files` flag allowed it to execute.

Is this expected behavior?  Will I be missing anything by leaving it out?

Comment: `library(flowCore)` should be in the post.

Comment: @Frank Sorry, I thought that was understood.  Please see above.

Comment: I know the authors of the flow packages monitor the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) but I'm not sure if they're here...